# MySQL SELECT query - one cell to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, select

In MySQL I have one particular cell with data something like this

```
5,6,7,8,9
```

If I need to search for specific 2 numbers one after another I do a query with **LIKE statement** for those 2 particular numbers. For ex. I need to check if there's a row with numbers **6 & 7** **in a row** I do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%,6,7,%' OR column LIKE '%,6,7' OR column LIKE '6,7,%'
```

It's little redundant and clumsy. If I 'convert' those numbers into multiple rows, for ex. every number would become it's own row with column '**numbers**' ordered with '**sort**' column so I know the order of rows.

```
id    numbers    sort
55     8         4
56     6         2
57     5         1
58     7         3
59     9         5
...
```

What's the identical query for this case? So I would have the same result as with the query above. I need to order the query with **sort** column and check if the numbers 6,7 are **occurring one after another** with that sorting.

Comment: t2.stop_sequence-1. You should put the OR in the second select that I showed you to be able to not care of the order of t1 and t2.

Comment: correct, I removed the comment already :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this. (if I understood right your problem). It will return nothing if the 2 numbers are not in sequence by the sort column.

```
select * 
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.sort=t2.sort+1
where t1.numbers=6 and t2.numbers=7
```

if you do not know which one should be first you can use it like this:

```
select * 
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.sort=t2.sort+1 or t1.sort+1=t2.sort
where t1.numbers=6 and t2.numbers=7
```

Comment: The numbers 6 and 7 are in the same table

Comment: So the table is called "SOMETABLE" then the query should look like  `select * 
from SOMETABLE t1
join SOMETABLE t2 on t1.sort=t2.sort+1
where t1.numbers=6 and t2.numbers=7` ?

Comment: Are the results (even duplicated) correct ? If so you can query only what you need and do something like select distinct t1.numbers,t2.numbers or similar with distinct. Duplicated records have to be removed based on a condition and as I do not know what you keep there I cannot know that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Are the numbery always incremented by one or can they have any value?

Comment: Numbers can have any values for ex. "2,456,241" and if I search for 456,241 'in a row' it should return me the result.

Comment: may i also tasks where these numbers come from and why you need to query them this way? maybe we can give you better proposals knowing the backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing the following table structure

```
id col1 col2 rowid
1  1 2 1
2  2 3 1
3  1 4 2
```

Comment: It's little problematic because the sizeof(numbers) isn't static. Sometimes it will be 3 numbers (1,2,3), sometimes 10 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and so on. But I need to make a search only for 2 in a row.